# Changing blockScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello everyone,**

I really need help here. I am trying to change the direction [blockScroll.js](http://www.dominikgorecki.com/download/block-scroll/) is animating. Instead of going up and down I'm trying to have it go left to right.

Please if anyone can help me out here I would really appreciate it

I've tried looking at the code just can't get it.

Line 49:

```
    var scrollDistance = $(window).height();
```

I tried changing the height to width, but nothing.

Could it be done using CSS only? Like a float left?

**Here is some of the html code. The stack on top on each other:**

```
<!-- Section: 1 Welcome Screen
        --------------------------------------------------------- -->
            <div id="sm-window-intro" class="intro">
                <section id="intro-text">

                </section>
            </div><!-- .intro div -->

        <!-- Section: 2 Overview : 1
        --------------------------------------------------------- -->
            <div id="sm-window" class="second ">

                <section id="sculptra-text">
                </section>

            </div><!-- .second div -->
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The it is not only the height that have been changed, but also the the display mode of divs. In other words you are trying to change the library. If I get right your desire you want to have a site in a horizontal view. So navigate using left and right directions instead of up and down.

So you can try it: //jsfiddle.net/mnn94crj/10/

If you want you can add a menu on top using css (position: fixed) and now add the menu links.

Comment: Here is what happens when I add your code:
[screens](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r90uwho1ngs97a5/AABQ38eYw4Fbdm9rpL-gA3KJa?dl=0)

The width only increase to double and the other divs are not going horizontal.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot open Dropbox links. I can try to help if you place part of your code on fiddle. Likely, your CSS has something that change the behavior of the divs.